# how to partitioning a laptop using both SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have recently bought a laptop with a 240 GB SSD and a 2T HDD drives. I want to install the OS(windows 10) on the SSD and the rest files on the HDD in order to speedup the machine. My questions are: 
1.should I split the SSD and HDD into smaller partitions and why? 
2.If I have to split them, What is the best partition size for both of them?

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't split the SSD, nor the HDD. (It doesnt really matter)

If you install Windows 10 on the SSD, the remaining data of the SSD will be still available.

You can use the HDD for the rest of your programs and data.

That's what I would do.

If you want to resize the partition I don't think there will be any major problem. Just keep in mind that a computer may use free space in SSD or harddriver instead of RAM for various reasons. (It happens for olders computers normally when the ram is full)

By the way, if you have problem installing windows on your SSD, my SSD needed to be initialized first. I used the device manager of my other pc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to split the SSD into two pieces, one of it large enough for only the OS and whatever must go on C:. [I have about 15 GB used there, so making it 40 GB is probably a good size, with some spare].

This way you can fully use the remainder for other things.

For the non-SSD, I would see no need to partition in any way - except if you want to install multiple OS.